# How can I load the new activity after login in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Basically, I want to start a new activity after login using the database. How can I do that?

**This is my login class**

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button btn_login;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String user = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                String type = "login";
                System.out.println("IN Onclick login");
                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getApplicationContext());
                backgroundTask.execute(type,user,pass);

                  if(backgroundTask.statusOK.equals("true"))     {
                      Intent loginIntent = new Intent(login.this,loggedIn.class);
                      startActivity(loginIntent);
                  }

            }




        });


    }


}
```

You can see in the code above that I am using this code to start my new activity after successful login, but this is not starting a new activity. I don't know why?

```
if(backgroundTask.statusOK.equals("true"))     {
                      Intent loginIntent = new Intent(login.this,loggedIn.class);
                      startActivity(loginIntent);
                  }
```

**This is BackgroundTask class**

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    Context context;
    public String statusOK="false";




    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.context = ctx;

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
          System.out.println("In doin");
        String type = strings[0];
        String loginURL = "http://192.168.10.119/log/login.php";
        String regURL = "http://192.168.10.119/log/log.php";

        if(type.equals("reg")){
            String name = strings[1];
            String pass = strings[2];
            try{
                URL url = new URL(regURL);
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

                    String insert_data = URLEncoder.encode("Username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+
                            "&"+URLEncoder.encode("Password","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8");

                    bufferedWriter.write(insert_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();

                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String result="";
                    String line="";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while((bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    result = stringBuilder.toString();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;




                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(type.equals("login")){
            System.out.println("In type = login");
            String name1 = strings[1];
            String pass1 = strings[2];
            try{
                URL url = new URL(loginURL);
                try {
                    System.out.println("In type = login try");
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

                    String login_data = URLEncoder.encode("Username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name1,"UTF-8")+
                            "&"+URLEncoder.encode("Password","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(pass1,"UTF-8");

                    bufferedWriter.write(login_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();

                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String result="";
                    String line="";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while((bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    result = stringBuilder.toString();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                    return result;



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        statusOk="true";

        Toast.makeText(context, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //super.onPostExecute(s);
    }



}
```

I have checked the connection between the database and my app is established and the app is running without any error.

You can see in the code above that I have created a public variable `statusOk` and initialize it with `"false"`. This variable is telling the **login class** that the user have entered his correct login credentials.

You can see that I have changed the value of `statusOk` to `"true"` **onPostExexute** method.

Now the problem is my new activity is not opening from the login class after successful login. Please give me a solution how can I open a new activity after Login with correct login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask is used to execute task in the background thread, (not the main thread from where you have called the `execute()` ).

Therefore in your code, `if` statement is executed just after you called the `execute()`, which still store the variable `statusOK` as false. Hence the condition is false.

The `postExecute()` method of asynctask is used to execute code in the main thread,

**My suggestion**: remove the `if` condition from the `Login` class, and check for the `if` condition in the `postExecute()`,

Comment: I want to open the new activity from login class, so how can I add the if with condition with Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,NextActivity.class); in background class

Comment: There is no way you can wait for asynctask to complete. If your purpose is to check the if statement in Login class,  you can call a function of Login class ( a function to check the if condition and startActivity() ) from postExecute() method.